# CAML query to add a ListItem in Sharepoint

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, soap, caml

my CAML query to add a ListItem (Wiki Page) doesn't work. I've tried several
fields, but Sharepoint always creates empty pages.

Here is my CAML so far:

```
    <Batch OnError="Continue">
        <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
         <Field Name="WikiField">My Wiki Content</Field>
        </Method>
      </Batch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<Batch OnError="Continue">        
     <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">         
          <Field Name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#WikiField">My Wiki Content</Field>        
     </Method>      
</Batch>
```

Comment: It didn't help. Thanks for your answer.