# Adding a ListItem to a list in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

I am trying to add an item to a list in Sharepoint.  At the moment I am trying to add the item via CAML

I can read the list, and query the list but I have not been able to add to the list.  All the examples that I have seen update the list,  I would expect that it should be reasonably similar process to add an item.

this is how I am testing it at the moment.
SPLists is a web reference to http:///_vti_bin/lists.asmx

```
    void Test(){
        var listService = new SPLists.Lists();

        string strBatch ="<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='Title'>Test</Field></Method>";

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

        System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");

        elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
        elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");

        elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
        XmlNode ndReturn = listService.UpdateListItems("TestList",elBatch);

        Console.Write(ndReturn.OuterXml); 
        Console.WriteLine("");

}
```

[someone already asked a similar/same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965581/caml-query-to-add-a-listitem-in-sharepoint) on SO but not answered

**Edit**
This is the error that I get

`<Results xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">

    <Result ID="1,New">

       <ErrorCode>0x81020026</ErrorCode>

       <ErrorText>The list that is referenced here no longer exists.</ErrorText>

    </Result>

</Results>`

When I setup the web reference pointed it at the correct site and even looked at the list in sharepoint to make sure that it is there.

Comment: (1) Add `try ... catch ...` around `UpdateListItems` and check if there's an exception thrown. (2) Here's an *add item* example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx.

Comment: yes I have done that. but the error is not very helpful.

Comment: Turned out to be more helpful than I thought. Once I found the problem the error made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found that solved my problem.

When I set up the Web Reference in visual studio I pointed it to the http://sharepointSite/subweb1/subweb2/_vit_bin/lists.asmx as the reference.

However when I went back and checked today it was pointing to http://sharepointSite/_vit_bin/lists.asmx.  manually changing it back to http://sharepointSite/subweb1/subweb2/_vit_bin/lists.asmx in the app.config file made all the difference.

@Kit +1 I also added in you suggestion as well.  With your suggetion and what I discovered about the web reference, it worked first time.

I ended up just creating a sub web with only 1 field (Title) just to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you probably need a small addition to your strBatch ([use this article as a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)): `<Field Name='ID'>New</Field>`

Which means you'll have something like:

```
string strBatch ="<Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='ID'>New</Field><Field Name='Title'>Test</Field></Method>";
```

Also, if you have any required fields on your list, you'll probably have to specify those as well.